# Update div every few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html page on which I call some photo from some website. This image is updated every 30seconds so I would like to update my div every 30 seconds if that is possible using javascript. I tried different things but couldn't wrap my mind around it. Some help would be appreciated.

Here is my html :

```
            <section class="stack-view">
            <ul class="stack-list">
                <li class="stack-1 cam-list-item">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <ul class="sub-cam">
                                <li>
                                    <p class="help-desc ps-note stack-name"></p>
                                    <img class="img"   alt="" >
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p class="help-desc ps-note stack-name"></p>
                                    <img class="img"  alt="" >
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p class="help-desc ps-note stack-name"></p>
                                    <img class="img"  alt="" >
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <p class="help-desc ps-note stack-name"></p>
                                    <img class="img"  alt="" >
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

And this is my javascript :

```
     var values = 
                      [ 
                          {url : "http://here/is/some/url/I/need"}, 
                          {url : "http://here/is/some/url/I/need"}, 
                          {url : "http://here/is/some/url/I/need"}, 
                          {url : "http://here/is/some/url/I/need"}
                      ];
    (function(){
        var i = 0;
        $('.img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr( "src", values[i].url );
            i++;
        });
    })();
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        var i = 0;
        $('.img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr( "src", values[i].url );
            i++;
        });
    }, 3000);
```

Any idea guys on how I can approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout` runs once, try using `setInterval` instead

Comment: and 3000ms is 3 seconds not 30 ;)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What goes wrong? Getting any errors?

Comment: The list won't update every 30 seconds. I't wont update at all. @showdev

Comment: I tried it @MathiasW it still does not work.

Comment: [Seems to work for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/1xxbhvt7/1/)

Comment: @showdev I wan't it to run every 1 second. According to your example it only runs once after 1 second.

Comment: Then that sounds like the problem statement. Not that "it won't update at all".

Comment: Yes you're right. I thought setTimeout() would fix my problem to reload the list every second but it won't. Any idea? @showdev

Comment: As @MathiasW said, `setInterval` runs once but `setInterval` will repeat on an interval.

Answer (score 2):

in this line:

```
(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $('.img').each(function() {
        **$(this).html(values[i].url);**
        i++;
    });
```

instead : `$(this).html(values[i].url);`
use: `$(this).attr( "src", values[i].url );`

Comment: yes you're right, that's how I did it but I didn't write it right. Thanks for pointing it out. :)